# Geometric mean of k smallest eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This problem comes from S. Boyd's *Convex Optimization*, problem 3.26(b). It states that the geometric mean of $k$ smallest eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix $X$ satisfies the following condition:
$$\left(\prod_{i=n-k+1}^n\lambda_i(X)\right)^{1/k}=\frac{1}{k}\inf\{\mathbf{tr}(V^TXV)|V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}, \text{det}V^TV=1\}$$
I thought of this as a consequence of the [AM-GM Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), since it is known that
$$\left(\prod_{i=n-k+1}^n\lambda_i(X)\right)^{1/k}=\left(\inf\{\prod_{i=1}^{k}（V^TXV)_{ii}|V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}, V^TV=I\}\right)^{1/k}$$
but how does the condition "$V^TV=I$" become "det$V^TV=1$"?

Comment: You are right $\det(V^TV) = 1$ seems to be an unnecessarily loose condition. $V^TV = I$ is more precise. (This might be a little late)

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be a $\leqslant$ sign in between the terms?